# Laravel update form - get correct selected state

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Within my update profile form, I have a select list for title. Admittedly, the items should be derived from the database however for the moment, I would like this particular select list to do the following..

1. Show the selected item on initial page load. So, if the $user['title'] is a 'Mrs', this is displayed.
2. Should laravel validation bring up errors on other form fields, and the user has changed the title to 'Mr', the selected state should be on the item 'Mr'.

I have the following so far, but it isn't working correctly.

```
<select name="title" id="title">
<option value="Mr" @if(($user['title']) == 'Mr') selected @else @if((Input::old('title')) == 'Mr') selected @endif @endif>Mr</option>
<option value="Mrs" @if(($user['title']) == 'Mrs') selected @else @if((Input::old('title')) == 'Mrs') selected @endif @endif>Mrs</option>
....
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the data for the select from your `Controller` and also uset the `Form` component to build the select in the `View`, for example:

In `Controller` method:

```
$users = User::lists('title', 'id');
return View::make('user')->with('users', $user);
```

In the `View`:

```
// By default, item with id 1 (the first item) will be selected
echo Form::select('title', $users, Input::old('title', 1), ['id'=>title]);
```

If you are using `Blade` then:

```
// By default, item with id 1 (the first item) will be selected
{{ Form::select('title', $users, Input::old('title', 1), ['id'=>title]) }}
```

Read the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists) properly. You are using `Laravel` with old school `PHP` coding.

Comment: I know I am using old school PHP and I acknowledged in my question.  However, I still need to know how to do this.